# How can you introduce php variables in this javascript code

Tags: javascript, php

I have this [javascript calendar plugin](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/download/) and this code to manage the events:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'month,agendaWeek',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'prev,next'
            },
            defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
            editable: true,
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: '2014-06-01'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2014-06-16T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2014-06-12T10:30:00',
                    end: '2014-06-12T12:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: '2014-06-13T07:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    url: 'http://google.com/',
                    start: '2014-06-28'
                }
            ]
        });
```

How can I introduce in events:[title,url,start] php variables? So, instead of writing in this file the title and start time of the event, I want to use php variables like $title and $date.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @derp how can this be a duplicate of that question? Anyway, I solved my issue with `json_encode` as suggested by moss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing PHP into inline JS or script tags is bad practice. It's hard to read and hard to maintain. What you want is to create a PHP file that you can send an HTTP/Ajax request to.

Javascript(using jQuery):

```
var events = $.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/api.php',
    data: { event: 'all' },
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET'
  })
  .fail(errHandler);

var calendarObj = {
  header: {
    left: 'month,agendaWeek',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'prev,next'
  },
  defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
  editable: true
};

events.done(function (data) {

  calendarObj.events = data;

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar(calendarObj);

});
```

api.php (simplified):

```
<?php

$events = array(
  array(
    'title' => 'Event 1',
    'start' => '2014-6-1'),
  array(
    'title' => 'Event 2',
    'start' => '2014-7-5'
);

$jsonResponse = json_encode($events);

HttpResponse::sendData(jsonResponse);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the php variable in there? assuming this is a .php page?

```
title: '<?php echo $title; ?>',
start: '<?php echo $startDate; ?>'
```

Comment: ok, thanks! I was using wrong quotes so that's why it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If it's part of a php file, you can simply use something like:

```
<?=$title?>
```

If it's not part of php file, make it part of a php file

Answer (score 0):

Simply `echo` the PHP variables in place of hard-coded strings. So

```
title: 'Birthday Party',
```

becomes

```
title: '<?php echo $title; ',
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you have specific `$title`,`$date` variables

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        //...
        events:[{
           title: "<?php echo $title;?>",
           start: "<?php echo $date;?>"
```

If you want to build the whole events property from say rows from a database

```
<?php
//do whatever database calls to get an associative array or array of objects 

?>
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        //...
        events:<?php echo json_encode($rows);?>,
        //...
```